# Windows 10 showing more keyboards than configured

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, input-languages

I know that keyboards doesn't work in any version of windows, but in win10 they fail in whole new level. I skip small problems like exactly configuring localization during setup, which is then not used etc.

The main problem is that I tried to set up keyboards correctly, it worked few hours and then win10 added some more keyboards that are not listed in the settings. How to fix it forever? ..I want only those 2 keyboards that are configured.
[image: Configured 2, seeing 4 keyboards]

Comment: Now I have opposite problem, when someone else logs into Windows 10 and then I use my profile, the last keyboard is not there :D

Answer (score 27):

I experienced the same issue.. I managed to fix it by adding the exact same keyboard in Settings (like it's not already added) and then removing it.

Comment: Ok, that worked, but I don't understand, why the problem occured etc.

Comment: Ok, so that isn't a solution, because after few hours, the keyboards have been added again...

Comment: I'm upvoting this answer as the described method seems to work for me (so far).

Comment: Using [this forum answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/2-keyboard-layouts-keep-appearing-even-they-arent/de256e6e-a68b-4451-90b6-ada43a64b4dc) steps and then doing the same as this answer solved the issue for me

Comment: mah man.. this works

Comment: lord, months with this. Just looged in to say this worked. thanks a ton.

Answer (score 4):

What seems to work for me was to change the value in "Advanced keyboard settings" for "Override for default input method" from "Use language list" to my preferred language e.g. "English US".

[image: How to remove useless keyboard languages added/showed by Windows 10]

Comment: This solved my problem at the time, but after some years, it came back even with this configuration set this way.